# Configuring Apache DBCP datasource in Jboss standalone.xml for Oracle connection

Tags: spring, oracle, jboss, jndi, apache-commons-dbcp

I want to configure DBCP datasource for connecting to oracle database.
I have option to configure it in either **jboss standalone.xml** or **Spring app-config.xml**.

I need to configure below properties of org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource

```
<property name="initialSize" value="10" />
<property name="maxActive" value="200" />
<property name="maxIdle" value="50" />
<property name="minIdle" value="10" />
<property name="maxWait" value="10000" />
```

Existing datasource config I have in standalone.xml is as follows:

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:/DS" pool-name="DS" enabled="true">
                <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE</connection-url>
                <driver>oracle</driver>
                <pool>
                    <min-pool-size>5</min-pool-size>
                    <max-pool-size>100</max-pool-size>
                    <prefill>true</prefill>
                    <flush-strategy>IdleConnections</flush-strategy>
                </pool>
                <security>
                    <user-name>user-name</user-name>
                    <password>password</password>
                </security>
                <validation>
                    <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleValidConnectionChecker"/>
                    <stale-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleStaleConnectionChecker"/>
                    <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleExceptionSorter"/>
                </validation>
                <timeout>
                    <idle-timeout-minutes>30</idle-timeout-minutes>
                </timeout>
            </datasource>
```

- Will the above properties be defined inside `<pool> </pool>`? And what will be the name of above properties while configuring?
- Existing datasource definition does not define `<datasource-class>`, is
  it's default value org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource?